# How to check to see if software is up to date with repository?

Tags: php, svn

I am having difficulties understanding [this incomplete documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.svn.php) for PECL SVN, so I am hoping someone with experience can tell me what to do.
Basically I want to

- find out what the revision the repository is on (http://example.com/repository)
- find out what revision the local fold /var/repository/ is on

in other words if revision 69 was committed to the repository and the servers version of the application is 42 I want PHP to notify the admin that the library is not up to date

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In plan SVN:

To get the current version of the remote repository you can use

```
svn log -r HEAD
```

And to get the version of the local working copy you can use

```
svn info
```

[svn_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-log.php) seems to be available in the documentation at least, but I can not find a wrapper for `svn info`. You may try to see if there is an svn_info method in PECL even though it is not in the documentation (if you suspect that the documentation is incomplete).